# JPA OneToOne relation on the same SQL table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Given the client class

```
public class Client {

 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private Address address;
  //..//
 }
```

and the Address Class

```
public class Address {

private int houseNumber;
private String streetName;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zipCode;
private String country;
//...//
}
```

I've created the address class since it is used in some other class and I didnt want to duplicate the code. Is there a way, using JPA, to explicitly have the Address information into my Client SQL table instead of creating an Address Table and use the primary key as link between the two?

Comment: Do you have all the info of class Address in the client table ? So for row you have all data listed in Client and Address class ?

Comment: Yeah, I think that would be ideal in my case. ( That being said, I'm still new with Java persistence and everything, so it may not be the best solution )

Comment: Why don't you want to create a Adress table? Try reading about database normalization.

Comment: In my opinion, if as an exemple, I have Client and Shop that use an Address, that means that in my Address Table, I would have Shop Addresses and Client Addresses which make no sense to me.

Comment: It is not relevant if an adress is stored because it belongs to a client or a shop. The shop can point to the address it needs and the client also. If you don't have a table for address and e.g. two shops have the same address you store the information twice. It increases your redundancy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a OneToOne relationship you can use Embeddable type.

```
@Entity
public class Client {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
}

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private int houseNumber;
    private String streetName;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;
    private String country;
}
```

This way you map a table client with the following column:

```
first_name, last_name, house_number, street_name, city, state, zip_code, country
```

And you can reuse the Address on any other entity that has the same columns in their table.